# How to get all child object in spinner with Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Please check the above image, 
I want to get "Basit" and "Kashif" in spinner from Firebase in Android

```
mdatabase.child("Orders/Particulars").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String Particulars = areaSnapshot.child("Basit").getValue(String.class);
                final String[] areas = {Particulars};
                ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(OrderActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas);
                areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                particular.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please share what you have done yourself and what kind of problems you face

Answer (score 0):

The below code will get the list of all the values...Finally add the list to the spinner wherever required.....

```
mDatabaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            BTLog.d(TAG, "There are " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " blog posts");
            isdList.clear();
            isdAdapter = new BTIsdAdapter(isdList);
            isdAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                BTIsdDetails post = postSnapshot.getValue(BTIsdDetails.class);
                BTIsdDetails btIsdDetails = new BTIsdDetails(post.getName(), post.getId());
                isdList.add(btIsdDetails);
                BTLog.d(TAG, " -------------------------- " + post.getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            BTLog.d(TAG, "The read failed: ");
        }
    });
```

BTIsdDetails is the pojo class

Comment: Change the code based on your requirements and try.

Answer (score 0):

As you need the keys to be added in spinner. Do the following thing..

```
mDatabaseref.child("Orders").child("Particulars").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            Log.d("Tag","Key : " + postSnapshot.getKey())
            // make string array of keys
       }
       // add spinner adapter code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        BTLog.d(TAG, "The read failed: ");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.